GitHub Pages Custom Domain with Squarespace Domain Not Propagating
I am trying to set up a custom domain for GitHub Pages, specifically with the domain lordimass.net
I bought the domain from Squarespace yesterday morning and have removed squarespace's default DNS records pointing the domain towards their servers and replaced it with the following:

I have also gone to the GitHub Repo and changed the custom domain to lordimass.net, and have now waited 24hrs before performing the DNS check. I currently get the error "Both lordimass.net and its alternate name are improperly configured. Domain does not resolve to the GitHub Pages server"
Also, using DNS checkers (Specifically dnschecker.org and whatsmydns.net) shows that the change has not propagated at all, and none of their servers across the world reflect the change in DNS records. At this point I'm sure I must have done something wrong because surely after a full 24hrs it should have resolved at least somewhere in the world, unless I'm mistaken and I'm just being impatient? If I am I'll just take this post down, honestly just looking for reassurance that I haven't done something dumb.

According to https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3alordimass.net&run=toolpage, no DNS entries seem to exist at all. https://mxtoolbox.com/emailhealth/lordimass.net/ reports DNS related issues such as "SOA Serial Number Format is Invalid" and "SOA Expire Value out of recommended range". I guess you should contact Squarespace and ask them about the issue.

@CBroe I figured out that I'm supposed to enter "@" instead of lordimass.net in the host field, and just the subdomain instead of the whole domain, not sure why that is or how I was supposed to know that without looking at the settings of a different domain owned by a friend, but here we are. Thanks for looking for me anyways :)

The host category should have an @ instead of the domain, the domain should not appear in the host column at all.
As well as this, for the CNAME records, the subdomain should be used alone, thus removing the domain from it. The corrected version of my setup above is therefore as follows:

